# Postgres search JSONB array containing objects for specific value

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column called "global_settings" in my users table. In here, users can configure a key called "aliases" which contains an array of objects of the form:

```
[{"email":"test1@test1.com","active":true},{"email":"test2@test2.com","active":true}]
```

What I'd like to do is search all users to see if one has an alias for a specific email, such as "test1@test1.com". One of my users has this in his aliases array as described above so I can test the search.

I tried these queries, but they don't return any results:

```
select * from users where team_id = 1 and (global_settings->'aliases')::jsonb @> '"test1@test1.com"'

select * from users where team_id = 1 and (global_settings->'aliases')::jsonb ? '"test1@test1.com"'

select * from users where team_id = 1 and (global_settings->'aliases')::jsonb ? 'test1@test1.com'
```

This however, does return all users on team 1 that have "aliases" configured, but of course doesn't allow me to find specific emails:

```
select * from users where team_id = 1 and (global_settings->'aliases')::jsonb is not null
```

Any ideas how I can search for users with specific email aliases?

EDIT:

With inspiration from Vao's answer below (Thank you!), I came up with this to get the full user row that contains a specific email:

```
select * from users as u 
inner join (select id,jsonb_array_elements(
(global_settings->'aliases')::jsonb)->>'email' = 'test1@test1.com' 
as alias from users 
where team_id = 1) as u2 
on u2.alias = true and u.id = u2.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with users(team_id,global_settings) as (values(1,'{"aliases":[{"email":"test1@test1.com","active":true},{"email":"test2@test2.com","active":true}]}'::jsonb)
)
, e as (select *,(jsonb_array_elements(global_settings->'aliases')->>'email' = 'test1@test1.com')::int from users where team_id = 1)
select *, bit_or(int4) from e group by team_id,global_settings,int4 having bit_or(int4)::boolean;
 team_id |                                              global_settings                                              | int4 | bit_or
---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------
       1 | {"aliases": [{"email": "test1@test1.com", "active": true}, {"email": "test2@test2.com", "active": true}]} |    1 |      1
(1 row)
```

here I use `jsonb_array_elements` to unnest array and `bit_or` (which returns true if at least one in group is true) to check if such value exists